# Material Expansion Panel not updating Nested ngFor Loops when array changes

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a nested ngFor loop inside a angular material expansion panel like so:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let artist of run.artists">
    <div *ngFor="let timesheet of artist.showTimesheets">{{timesheet}}</div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
<mat-accordion
```

I want to be able to programmatically change the *showTimesheets* for a particular
artist in the component like so:

```
changeShowTimesheets(artist) {
  artist['showTimesheets'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

However when I call this method, although I can see when printed out in the console that the artist does indeed change it's timesheets, it is not changing the displayed 's

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here... Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know for sure how the TS part is implemented. But here is a working version for you.

```html
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let artist of run.artists">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title> Panel Header Title </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <p>Panel Body</p>
    <div *ngFor="let timesheet of artist?.showTimesheets">{{ timesheet }}</div>
    <br />
    changeShowTimesheets: <button (click)="changeShowTimesheets(artist)">change timesheets to 5</button>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  run = {
    artists: [
      { showTimesheets: [1,2,3] },
      { showTimesheets: [1,2,3,4] },
      { showTimesheets: [1,2,3,4,5] },
    ],
  };
  constructor() {}

  changeShowTimesheets(artist) {
    artist['showTimesheets'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expansion-panel-example-xx6znn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts